# How use Eclipse to develop Google Modules for Google Cloud?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How do I use Eclipse to develop Google Modules (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) for Google Cloud?

Here's why I'm asking...

I've been using App Engine and recently decided to use Google Modules.  I wanted to start completely from scratch to ensure I had all the latest and greatest Google technology.  So I uninstalled my development environment and began the process of reinstalling.  To ensure I did everything the "right" way, I went to Google and searched for "Google app engine".  I thought this would ensure I came in through the "front door" and would not get off track.

The top result (an ad) for my query "Google app engine" was for https://cloud.google.com/products/app-engine/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=appengine-search&gclid=CPWg6eef670CFYdlfgodI1oAWw.  This is actually not Google app engine.  It's in fact Google Cloud.  But it appears that Google App Engine is a component of Google Cloud.

So I thought I should start developing using the Google Cloud tools rather than the Google App Engine tools.  But the Google Cloud tools don't seem to have instructions for developing with Eclipse.  Also, I was told by someone at Google that Google Cloud projects have Project IDs wheres Google App Engine projects have App IDs.

So how do I develop Java software for Google Cloud that uses Google Modules (or some equivalent) using Eclipse?

By the way, I use Windows (64 bit).

Thank you!

Comment: You can start from this page: Installing Google Plugin for Eclipse https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download

Comment: If you have an existing App Engine application, its _App ID_ will be the Google Cloud Platform _Project ID_.  For a new project, you can create it in the Google [Cloud developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) and develop your App Engine modules in Java using the App Engine SDK.  You can use the Google Plugin for Eclipse as alex suggested.

Comment: Thank you tx802, I will be trying your suggestion. One clarification--since my app will use Google Modules (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/), can I use the Google Plugin for Eclipse (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) or do I need to use Eclipse Web Tools Platform (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform)?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky I am still looking for an answer.. Have you found  anything?